# How to check status of long lasting ibm_db connection in python

Tags: python, db2

I'm developing and API that reads data from DB2 and returns corresponding result (using Flask on Python). Initially I had connection open on each API call but since number of connections per second is growing I thought it's better to open DB connection once and re-open it only if it closed/failed for any reason. And that is exactly what I can't do because I can't find a function or method that return connection status. I tried:

```
conn = ibm_db.connect(dbname, dbuser, dbpswd)
if conn:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
print(conn)

ibm_db.close(conn)
if conn:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
print(conn)}
```

It returned:

```
ok
<ibm_db.IBM_DBConnection object at 0xa000000012bd530>
ok
<ibm_db.IBM_DBConnection object at 0xa000000012bd530>
```

so this definitely doesn't work for closed connection. Is there a way to check if previously opened connection is still alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At python level there is `bool ibm_db.active(IBM_DBConnection connection)` method which returns the True or False.

You can also run a watchdog query periodically.

Did you investigate the [pconnect](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbpconnect)() method for your use case, it may be more appropriate.?

Remember that the TCPIP heartbeat on the connection may also expire if the connection is idle for longer than a certain period (for example 2 hours), and the Db2-server may close the connection in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have just found the answer (as always right after I submitted the question) and got back here to close it. Yes, I have stuck upon pconnect and planning to use it, I just provided example that I had by my hand, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Sure, sorry, newbie here, didn't really know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Do this....

```
try:
    ibm_db.close(conn)
    print('Disconnected')
except:
    print('Error Still connected')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).